# Sequence Lemma and statistical convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

We know that from the ***sequence lemma*** : if a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $A$ converges to $\ell$, then $\ell\in \bar A$.
Conversely, if the space is first countable, then $\ell\in \bar A$ implies that $\exists$ a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $A$ converges to $\ell$.

Also, every convergent sequence is statistically convergent sequence (and in this case limits & statistical limits are same). But the converse isn't true.

**My question :** If a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $A$ **converges statistically** to $\ell$, does $\ell$ belong to $\bar A$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a  statistically convergent sequence?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos See definition 1.1 from the article https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/136236/MathSlov_30-1980-2_6.pdf

Comment: As an answer below pointed out, this is true in general for convergence along an ideal (a filter). Still, I will point out that for statistical convergence the situation is easier, since then you have a subsequence which is convergent in the usual sense to $\ell$. (In fact, you have a subsequence on a set which has density equal to one. I'll also mention that an analogous property holds for ideals which are called P-ideals.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is, in fact, quite trivial. Say there is a neighborhood $A=(\mathscr l-\epsilon, \mathscr l+\epsilon)$ of $\mathscr l$ such that $A$ contains no $x_n$. Then $A_\epsilon=\Bbb N$. Obviously, we have $\delta(\Bbb N)=1$. Thus, $\{x_n\}$ cannot converge statistically to $\mathscr l$.

Comment: My Qn : If a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $A$ **converges statistically** to $\ell$, does $\ell$ belong to $\bar A$? But you are discussing about some sequence which is not convergent statistically to $\ell$. Even unnecessarily you have assumed that $\ell \in \mathbb R$ and $\exists A\ni\ell$ which contains no $x_n$. Why? Your answer is purely irrelevant to my question.

Comment: @BijanDatta This is the contrapositive. I proved $\mathscr l\notin \overline{A} \Rightarrow \{x_n\}$ doesn't converge to $\mathscr l$ statistically, which is equivalent to $\{x_n\}$ converge to $\mathscr l$ statistically $\Rightarrow \mathscr l\in \overline{A}$

Comment: Yes. You are absolutely **correct**. It's my fault of understanding. Please make some edit of your answer, I want to +1 you.

Comment: @BijanDatta That's fine. Mistakes are a fact of life.

Answer (score 4):

So we have a "notion of smallness" $I$, an ideal on $\mathbb{N}$, i.e. a collection of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ that contains all finite sets and is closed under shrinking ($A \in I,  B \subseteq A \implies B \in I$) and closed under finite unions ($A, B \in I \implies A \cup B \in I$). We also demand that $\mathbb{N} \notin I$ to avoid trivialities.

It is a dual notion to a proper filter. In the paper this ideal is the sets of density $0$ (wrt the counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$), which clearly obeys all the ideal properties. In that case $x_n \to x$ wrt $I$ is called "statistical convergence". And $x_n \to x$ wrt an ideal $I$ (in the usual topology) iff

$$\forall \varepsilon >0: E((x_n), \varepsilon):=\{n \in \mathbb{N}: |x_n - x| \ge \varepsilon\} \in I$$

i.e. there are only "$I$-few" terms of the sequence outside the $\varepsilon$-ball around $x$ for any $\varepsilon$.

As finite sets are always in $I$, if $x_n \to x$ topologically, $x_n \to x$ for any ideal $I$.

Now suppose $x_n \to x$ for an ideal $I$ and all $x_n \in A$. If $B(x_n, \varepsilon)\cap A = \emptyset$ then $\mathbb{N}= E((x_n), \varepsilon)$, as $$n \in \mathbb{N}\rightarrow x_n \in A \rightarrow x_n \notin B(x, \varepsilon) \rightarrow |x_n -x| \ge \varepsilon \rightarrow n \in E((x_n), \varepsilon)$$

and this contradicts $x_n \to x$ under $I$ as $\mathbb{N} \notin I$.

So indeed $B(x,\varepsilon) \cap A \neq \emptyset$ and so $x \in \overline{A}$ as $\varepsilon >0$ was arbitrary. So under very mild conditions we indeed have the required property. All we need is convergence under an ideal (in fact it's much more common to consider the dual filter (the complements of the members of $I$) and talk about convergence along an ultrafilter. It comes down to the same thing.